# Javascript regex to match part of the string but not the whole string

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regex: `(-?\d+)-(-?\d+)`.

The purpose is to match strings that denote ranges, including negative ones. For example:

- `1-10`
- `0-100`
- `-1-10`, but also:
- `-100--10`

Then with my regex, I will capture the first number, the last, but also the whole string. In Angular:

```
let regExp : RegExp = RegExp('(-?\\d+)-(-?\\d+)', 'g');
let values: RegExpExecArray = regExp.exec('-100--10');
```

From the `values` result, I can use positions `values[1]` and `values[2]`, as `values[0]` is reserved for the whole string.

Obviously, the above works for me, but do you have any idea how to make my regex more precise? I.e. *I don't want the whole string to be matched*.

Comment: What do you mean by "more precise"?

Comment: What is `AppConstants.ROLLING_DEP_DATE_REGEX`? Why not use the regexp to match what you describe? (e.g. `/(-?\d+)-(-?\d+)/g`)

Comment: Based on your comments, I updated the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern `(-?\\d+)` is repeating so you can use only this pattern to match in `text`.

```
let pattern = RegExp('(-?\\d+)', 'g')
let text = '-100--10'
text.match(pattern)   //output: ["-100", "-10"]
```

This way, you don't have to match entire string.

Comment: @user1485864 Did this helped you?

Comment: From your answer I understand that my question does not make sense. Indeed, I have to match the whole input string, as I need be certain that the two patterns `(-?\d+)` are separated by a `-`.
Thanks!